# What is the advantage of using Java applets?

Tags: java

Why use Java/Java applets?  jQuery, PHP, MySQL, CSS, etc. are quite popular right now.  Java is a little clunky (no sub-pixel text rendering, wait for the coffee cup).  Is it a dying language or still in use?

Comment: Given that 'Java' is the second most popular tag on Stackoverflow, I hardly suspect that it is dying or not in use...

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice that :P.  Oops...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. For instance, coding a game in JavaScript / jQuery is a lot more difficult, and the results are much more limited than when using Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring some of the abilities of a controlled desktop app to be delivered over the web with applets.